# Neo4j: How can we compare one relationship property with another relationship property and modify the relationship accordingly

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j db and I will try to explain my issue. So I have a list of RFID tags and I am adding the start time end time and duration of these tags when contacted with each other. I would like to iterate through these relations and find whether this start time and end time of one relation coincides with the other relation and then do some modification to the relation. Below is my relation.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| m.tagId | n.tagId | rel                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1       | 2       | [:CONTACTED {StartTime: 6.3, Duration: 2.7, EndTime: 9}] |
| 1       | 2       | [:CONTACTED {StartTime: 6, Duration: 2.3, EndTime: 8.3}] |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I need to do is, when StartTime of relation 1 is <= EndTime  of relation 2 and  StartTime of relation 2 is <=  EndTime of relation 1 then modify the relation like this

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| m.tagId | n.tagId | rel                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1       | 2       | [:CONTACTED {StartTime: 6, Duration: 3, EndTime: 9}] |
```

That is new relation's StartTime is MIN(6,6.3) and EndTime is MAX(8.3,9)

What I am looking for is a nested loop to iterate through all the relationships and check the condition then add/delete the relationship. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: You should eliminate the redundant `Duration` property since its value can always be calculated from the other 2 properties, and keeping it complicates your code.

Comment: @cybersam But we need that property also for our purpose

Comment: Can you explain why calculating the difference between `EndTime` and `StartTime` is not sufficient?

Comment: @cybersam We only need to display the duration in the front end. We can eliminate this and do the difference at the other end, which is also fine.